# SQL Server : select rows applying different where condition based on two column

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have list of suppliers with orders from different dates in `tbl_supplier_orders`.

I want to select only orders as per rule:

- If supplier_name: A,B,C order_date: 2016-02-19
- If supplier_name: P,Q,R order_date: 2016-03-12
- If supplier_name: M,N order_date: 2016-03-15
- If supplier_name: W,X,Y,Z order_date: 2016-05-17
- and rest of all supplier records from 2016-01-01

The columns are `order_name`, `order_date`, `supplier_name`, `address`, `cost`.

My initial approach is :

```
 select 
     * 
 from 
     tbl_supplier_order t1
 where
     t1.order_date >= CONVERT(date, '2016-01-01')
     and (t1.order_date < CONVERT(date, '2016-02-19') 
          AND t1.supplier_name not in ('A','B','C'))
     and (t1.order_date < CONVERT(date, '2016-03-12') 
          AND t1.supplier_name not in ('P','Q','R'))
     and (t1.order_date < CONVERT(date, '2016-03-15') 
          AND t1.supplier_name not in ('M','N'))
     and (t1.order_date < CONVERT(date, '2016-05-07') 
          AND t1.supplier_name not in ('W','X','Y','Z'))
```

Comment: did you forget the question?

Comment: Yes I need to add the question mark probably !!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to do?

```
If supplier_name: A,B,C order_date:2016-02-19
```

Are you saying one of your conditions is you only want to select rows where supplier_name is A,B,C and the order date is 2016-2-19, and the other conditions follow (it can be any of the other combinations as well)?

Comment: I want to select all the rows of A,B,C with date>2016-02-19 union all the rows of P,Q,R with date>2016-03-12 and so on and there are many other suppliers whose i need to show all data from 2016-01-01

Comment: Magnus's answer should work, you just needed to change your ANDs to ORs. If not let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested this but maybe you can try something like this.

```
select * from tbl_supplier_order t1 where
(t1.order_date>CONVERT(date,'2016-01-01') AND t1.supplier_name not in ('A','B','C','P','Q','R','M','N','W','X','Y','Z'))
OR (t1.order_date>CONVERT(date,'2016-02-19') AND t1.supplier_name in ('A','B','C'))
OR (t1.order_date>CONVERT(date,'2016-03-12') AND t1.supplier_name in ('P','Q','R'))
OR (t1.order_date>CONVERT(date,'2016-03-15') AND t1.supplier_name in ('M','N'))
OR (t1.order_date>CONVERT(date,'2016-05-17') AND t1.supplier_name in ('W','X','Y','Z'))
```